# React/Redux - Trigger action once previous action has completed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm building my first app with React + Redux and I have come across an issue and I'm not sure of the best way to deal with it.

I have a "Filter" and a "List" component. The list is just a list of records and the contents of the list is determined by the filter settings. This is how I think it should work:

- Filter field is changed in the Filter component
- Redux 'FILTER_UPDATE' action is fired, this triggers a post request to the server with the new filter settings
- Filter reducer updates the 'filter' state to reflect the new filter settings in React

The next part is where I am getting stuck:

- Once the update filter AJAX request is completed I need to trigger the action that fetches the list items again so the server can return the list based on the new filter settings

Here's what I have tried. This is the function in the filter component which fires the action:

```
updateFilter(event) {
    const field = event.target.getAttribute('name');
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.props.updateFilter(field,value); // Updates the filter
    this.props.getList(); // Fetches the new filtered list
}
```

The problem is that the `getList()` action is fired too quickly. I need to wait for the `updateFilter()` AJAX request to complete so that the server is aware of the filter settings when it resends the items.

Which is the best way to trigger the `getList()` action but only once the `updateFilter()` AJAX request is completed?

Here are the two actions `updateFilter()` and `getList()`:

```
// Update filter
export function updateFilter(field,value) {

    const response = axios.post(API_ROOT+'/filter/update',{
        field: field,
        value: value
    });

    return {
        type: UPDATE_FILTER,
        payload: {field, value}
    }
}

// Get items
export function getList() {

    const response = axios.get(API_ROOT+'/item');

    return {
        type: GET_LIST,
        payload: response
    }
}
```

Here are the relevant parts from the List and Filter reducers:

```
// Filter reducer
case 'UPDATE_FILTER':
     return update(state,{
        [action.payload.field]: { $set: action.payload.value }
 });

// List reducer
case 'GET_LIST':
     return action.payload.data;
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: The chapter on [Async Actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) in the docs goes over this - basically, you need to use a middleware like [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many lib and solution to do that, you can start by looking at [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) that can be suited for your implementation. It aims to manage async action that can fire another action.

Answer (score 2):

At least you should wait server answer:

```
export function getList() {

    axios.get(API_ROOT+'/item').then(function (response) {
       return {
           type: GET_LIST,
           payload: response
       };
    });
}
```

See [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) examples